# В двумерном массиве изменить порядок элементов в каждом столбце на обратный

Tags: c++

Помогите решить задачу, пробовал с помощью swap()ни как не выходит. Может кто подскажет, буду признателен!

```
'#include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<ctime>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        srand(time(NULL));
        const int n = 3;
        const int m = 4;
        int a[n][m];


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                a[i][j] = rand() % 10;
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                int temp = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }'
```

Что то такое пробую, но все равно не выходит!

Comment: Что, по вашему, делает строчка `a[i][j] = a[i][j];`?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю, нашел такой вариант в интернете!

Comment: @YosyaShifoner вы бы сначала познакомились с основами языка прежде чем что-то писать. Заодно и с логикой! Вы же просто присваиваете элементу его же значение и вам это ни о чем не говорит

Comment: Мой косяк, там не  a [i] [j] = a [ i ] [ j ]; , а a [ i ] [ j ] = a [ j ] [ i ];

Comment: @YosyaShifoner даже в током случае ваш массив должен быть исключительно квадратным - иначе будет ошибка. Да и судя по вопросу - это не то что вам нужно, так как в этом случае строки и столбцы просто поменяются местами (если не ошибаюсь)

Answer (score 4):

Если вам нужен обратный порядок в строках, то подойдет что-то вроде этого:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < (m / 2); j++) {
        int temp = a[i][m - j - 1];
        a[i][m - j - 1] = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: @YosyaShifoner это нужно уточная в вопросах! Но даже если и так, то просто замените `n` на `m` и наоборот - и все будет работать. Тут фишка в алгоритме

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!